# How to have UITextView becomeFirstResponder after touching its UIView subview?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uiview, uitextview, becomefirstresponder

**UPDATE**: I found a [simple solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6221109/how-to-have-uitextview-becomefirstresponder-after-touching-its-uiview-subview/6234110#6234110). I knew there was one!

I have a `UIView` subclass called `tipBalloon` that I've added as a subview of a `UITextView`, but when I touch `tipBalloon`, it doesn't focus the text view even though `tipBalloon.userInteractionEnabled = YES` (by default).

How do I make it so that when I touch `tipBalloon`, the touch is forwarded to the `UITextView`? Shouldn't this happen automatically?

Here is an example:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

    UITextView *payTextView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5.0f, 30.0f, 180.0f, 100.0f)];
    [window addSubview:payTextView];

    UIView *tipBalloon = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(6.0f, 10.0f, 100.0f, 30.0f)];
    tipBalloon.backgroundColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
    [payTextView addSubview:tipBalloon];
    [tipBalloon release];

    window.backgroundColor = [UIColor brownColor];
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

**UPDATE**: A simpler solutions is just to set `tipBalloon.userInteractionEnabled = NO`. This causes the `tipBalloon` to ignore any touches, which then get passed to the `UITextView`. I learned this technique from [@elizablock](http://twitter.com/#!/elizablock) while watching the [WWDC 2011 video Advanced Scroll View Techniques](http://bit.ly/iqpttM).

Here's a solution based on @dredful's (just tidied up a bit). Add the following block of code just before `[tipBalloon release];`:

```
// Focus payTextView after touching payTextExample.
UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:
                                     payTextView action:@selector(becomeFirstResponder)];
[tipBalloon addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];
[singleTap release];
```

Comment: Nice +1, however the intent of my solution was to be reusable.

Answer (score 1):

If the `UIView` is a subview of your textView, you should be able to call `[tipBalloon.superview becomeFirstResponder]`

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question directly, you need to register the interaction with the `UIView`. For a `UIView` it is probably best to add a `UITapGestureRecognizer` to your `tipBalloon`

Inside of your `tipBalloon`'s `viewDidAppear:` you can put:

```
[self addGestureRecognizerToUIView:self.view];
```

The have these methods in your `tipBalloon`

```
- (void)addGestureRecognizerToUIView:(id)thisUIView
{
    // Single Tap
    UITapGestureRecognizer *thisTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self 
                                                                               action:@selector(handleTap:)];
    thisTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
    [thisUIView addGestureRecognizer:thisTap];
    [thisTap release];

}

- (void)handleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)gesture {
    [yourUITextView becomeFirstResponder];
}
```

This will add a tap to your `tipBalloon` UIView. When the tap fires it can then set the `UITextView` as the first responder.

Comment: Thank you, but shouldn't the touch on `tipBalloon` be forwarded to the `UITextView` automatically since `tipBalloon` is a subview of the `UITextView`?

Comment: Have u set `tipBalloon.exclusiveTouch = NO`? However, that should be the default which one should expect would "roll up" to the `UITextView` as you say. Honestly I am not sure why it is not doing so now.

Comment: No, I didn't set `tipBalloon.exclusiveTouch = NO`. And, `[tipBalloon nextResponder]` returns the `UITextView`. Maybe this is a UIKit bug. Anyway, your solution worked! Thanks! I [tidied it up a bit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6221109/how-to-have-uitextview-becomefirstresponder-after-touching-its-uiview-subview/6234110#6234110).